# Grab the cell value before Excel applies auto-formatting

Tags: c#, excel

I need to grab the value that a user has entered into a cell before Excel applies the auto-formatting to the cell. For example 1230E45 gets converted into 1.23E+48 (scientific notation).

I'm aware the user can avoid this issue by pre-formatting the cell as text, but I don't want him\her to do that every time.

Is there a way to capture keydown on edit mode to store what the user has entered?

or a better idea....

Comment: No events fire when a cell is in edit mode, so there's no way to pre-format the value. The closest point available after the edit is the `worksheet_change` event I think, and that's likely too late for your purposes. Presumably "1230E45" is not really a number but something else? I think your only option here is to pre-format the cell as text: if there is some specific range where a user might enter this type of value then you could maybe do that in the `worksheet_selectionchange` event.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm aware the user can avoid this issue by pre-formatting the cell as
>   text, but I don't want him\her to do that every time.

In case input cells are located in certain defined region, let's say 1 or several columns - you may **preformat the entire region as Text** using usual "Cell properties" dialog.

Perhaps that's a bit straightforward, but there's nothing in your input that makes my solution entirely impossible)

Answer (score 0):

Excel only formats numbers for display purposes - the underlying value is stored as a double precision floating point accessible using Cell.Value2. 
So presumably you are talking about Excel's automatic conversion of some things that look like numbers (1230E45 ... 24-Sep-1992 etc) into numbers when you want them to be text.
 If so some possible solutions are:

- capture the data in a form and then transfer it to Excel in the form
  you want
- postprocess the data after it has been entered and convert it back to the form you want
- selectively preformat cells as text (effectively pre-create an on-worksheet form for the user to fill in)
- use on-sheet controls such as data validation, listboxes etc to allow pick-from list user entry